# Is there a better way to use filter array in this case?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to implement a function that returns an array.

The goal is to filter an array for getting the yellow fruits, but if there is a **Banana** then just return all the bananas instead of all the yellow fruits.

My question is if there is another way to enhance this function to avoid filtering twice and just have one filter call.

This is just plain Javascript. I can use the newest features of JS.

```
let fruits = [
    {name: 'Apple', color: 'Red', size: 'Small'},
    {name: 'Banana', color: 'yellow', size: 'Medium'},
    {name: 'Orange', color: 'orange', size: 'Big'},
    {name: 'Mango', color: 'yellow', size: 'Medium'},
    {name: 'Guava', color: 'yellow', size: 'Medium'},
];

function getFruitsThatAreYellowButReturnOnlyBananaIfExists(fruits)
{
    let yellowFruits = [];

    const bananaFruit = fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.name === "Banana")
        .map(banana => `I'm a banana ${banana.size}`);

    if (bananaFruit.length > 0) {
        return bananaFruit;
    }

    yellowFruits = fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.color === 'yellow')
        .map(yellowFruit => `I'm ${yellowFruit.name} my color is yellow , my size is ${yellowFruit.size}`);

    return yellowFruits;
}

const fruitsOrBanana = getFruitsThatAreYellowButReturnOnlyBananaIfExists(fruits);
```

I expect the result `[ "I'm a banana Medium" ]` if there is a `banana` in the `fruits` array, and an array of message like this:

```
[ "I'm Mango my color is yellow , my size is Medium", "I'm Guava my color is yellow , my size is Medium" ]
```

if there is no banana in the `fruits` array.

Comment: At quick glance, I personally always advocate for one `.reduce()` over `.filter()`+`.map()` to reduce the amount of iterations. Other than that I'm not too sure what you're asking - your code seems to output exactly what you desire. By "better way", what do you mean, specifically?

Comment: In terms of running time, if that's what you're asking, you're better off just regular old for looping and handling it all at once -- best case O(1) and worst case O(n), as opposed to always O(n) in this case. Plus basic for loops are faster than functions like .map anyway.

Comment: If the code works, it's not a good question for stackoverflow unless you have a very specific request or concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [for ... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to iterate only once over the array of objects. While iterating, you can collect the `Bananas` in one array and the yellow fruits into another. Then, you can return the array of `bananas` if there is any, otherwise return the array of yellow fruits.

```js
let fruits=[{name:'Apple',color:'Red',size:'Small'},{name:'Banana',color:'yellow',size:'Medium'},{name:'Orange',color:'orange',size:'Big'},{name:'Mango',color:'yellow',size:'Medium'},{name:'Guava',color:'yellow',size:'Medium'},];

function getFruitsThatAreYellowButReturnOnlyBananaIfExists(fruits)
{
    let yellowFruits = [], bananas = [];

    for (const {name, color, size} of fruits)
    {
        if (name.toLowerCase() === "banana")        
            bananas.push(`I'm a banana ${size}`);
        else if (color.toLowerCase() === "yellow")
            yellowFruits.push(`I'm ${name} my color is yellow , my size is ${size}`);
    }

    return bananas.length ? bananas : yellowFruits;
}

console.log(getFruitsThatAreYellowButReturnOnlyBananaIfExists(fruits));
fruits[1].name = "lemon";
console.log(getFruitsThatAreYellowButReturnOnlyBananaIfExists(fruits));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: @Kaiido I have updated to meet that, I missundestood the goal after reading this: _if there is a Banana then just returning the banana instead all yellow fruits_

Answer (score 1):

One way you could write this that isn't fancy but that would probably be easily understood later on:

```
const bananas = [];
const yellowFruits = [];

//Only requires 1 loop.
fruit.forEach(f => {
  if (f.name === 'Banana') { 
    bananas.push(`I'm a banana ${f.size}`);
  }
  else if (f.color === 'yellow') { 
    yellowFruits.push(`I'm ${f.name} my color is yellow , my size is ${f.size}`); 
  }
});

if (bananas.length > 0) {
  return bananas;
}
else {
  return yellowFruits;
}
```